# PIVOT, how to convert other than specified rows to a column?

Tags: oracle, select, plsql, oracle11g, pivot

I have `ID` and `NUMBER` columns in my table.

IDs can be something from 1 to 200, and NUMBERs can be anything from 1 to 100000.

The below code works perfect.

```
SELECT *
FROM PIVOT_DATA
PIVOT (
    SUM(NUMBER)
    FOR (ID)
    IN (1 , 2)
    );
```

But, I want to select 3 columns (1, 2, Others), how can I select all the other IDs other than 1 or 2 ? It should be something like the code below, but what?

```
SELECT *
FROM PIVOT_DATA
PIVOT (
    SUM(NUMBER)
    FOR (ID)
    IN (1 , 2, OTHERS)
    );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `CASE` statement to convert your column into the three values that you want to pivot.

```
CASE ID
WHEN 1 THEN '1'
WHEN 2 THEN '2'
ELSE 'OTHERS'
END
```

Then pivot on that value instead of ID.

Answer (score 3):

```
WITH TAB AS (SELECT   CASE ID
                         WHEN 1 THEN '1'
                         WHEN 2 THEN '2'
                         ELSE 'OTHERS'
                      END
                         ID, num
               FROM   PIVOT_DATA)
SELECT   *
  FROM   TAB 
  PIVOT ( SUM (NUM) 
          FOR ( ID ) 
                    IN ( 1 , 2 , 'OTHERS' ) );
```